# How to save Notepad++ Compare plugin settings?

Tags: notepad++, colors, plugins

I would like to save the color settings of the Compare plugin in Notepad++.
The following example shows the problem.
It happens only on a pc (at work) where I'm not the administrator.
I have no problem on my own pc (at home).

Suppose I have two files. First file:

```
Pippo
Pluto
Paperino
```

Second file:

```
Pluto
Paperino/a
Minnie
```

If I compare them, I get:

[image]

as you can see, the results are unreadable.

Of course, it is easily solvable choosing other colors with Plugins > Compare > Settings:

[image]

Changing the colors, now the results are readable:

[image]

The problem is that I have to set the Compare colors every time I close and reopen Notepad++.

Is there a way to make them permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.
I saved `ComparePlugin.ini` with the colors I chose:

```
[Colors]
Added=32768
Removed=128
Changed=4227200
Moved=16770764
Highlight=427007
Alpha=100
```

at the path

```
C:\***USER***\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: @help-info.de Thank you for the info, but look at my reputation on TeX Stack Exchange :D